# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Webshare api

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I am trying to implement web share api of android chrome in jekyll posts page. Below is my code.

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('share-btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if(navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
        title: {{ page.title }},
        text: {{ page.content }},
        url: {{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Success'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }

  });

</script>
```

But I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error in console on line `title: {{ page.title }},`. Please correct my code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that your javascript code is not processed by Jekyll.

Be sure to set a [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) in any file your want to be processed.

```
---
# even an empty front matter is ok
---
<script>
  document.querySelector('share-btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if(navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
        title: '{{ page.title }}',
        text: '{{ page.content }}',
        url: '{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}'
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Success'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Still I get same error. I added in _layout/post.html page. https://govtexam.justinechacko.in/maharashtra/2018/12/29/11.html

Comment: This new error comes from the fact that you're not enclosing your string in quotes or double quotes. You also have to ensure that provided strings have quotes and/or double quotes properly escaped. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, new error comes`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

Comment: My html is `<button class="btn btn-danger shadow-sm my-2 my-sm-0 share-btn5" type="submit" value="submit">More</button>`

Comment: Sorry but but my answer resolved you problem. You can then approve it and ask a new question about your new problem. And the solution is `document.querySelector('.share-btn5')` note the dot before share-btn5

Comment: I mark it as solution. Still I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` even after adding `document.querySelector('.share-btn5')`

Comment: As I've told you, once a problem is resolved, comment are not the place to solve additional problems. Note that your last problem is resolved on the page you've mentionned, and that the new error is `SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break` where **unescaped line break** is a line break that needs to be replaced by `/r` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The values for the share properties are essentially strings, not what you have supplied. This is from the Mozilla documentation:

```
    var sharePromise = window.navigator.share(data);

data = An object containing data to share. At least one of the following fields must be specified. Available options are:

url: A USVString representing a URL to be shared.
text: A USVString representing text to be shared.
title: A USVString representing the title to be shared.


    navigator.share({
      title: document.title,
      text: 'Hello World',
      url: 'https://developer.mozilla.org',
    }); // share the URL of MDN
```

did you mean:

```
  navigator.share({
    title: page.title,
    text: page.content,
    url: site.url + page.url
  });
```