# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in javascript - Web share api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement web share api of android chrome in jekyll posts page. Below is my code. my code is in `_layout/post.html`.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger shadow-sm my-2 my-sm-0 share-btn2" type="submit" value="submit">More</button>
<script>
  document.querySelector('.share-btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if(navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
        title: '{{ page.title }}',
        text: '{{ page.content }}',
        url: '{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}'
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Success'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }
  });
</script>
```

Now I get Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

error in console on line

`text: <p>NB: If you are viewing in mobile, rotate your mobile to landscape
mode to view pdf clearly</p>`

https://govtexam.jus.in/maharashtra/2018/12/29/11.html

Comment: Look at the rendered JS. You have `\n`s in one of those strings, which makes the syntax invalid. Either remove the `\n`s or use a template literal instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am newbie, Please check the link now if did correct. I added `, but still have same error. Can you tell how to use literals

Comment: See the ``text: '`<p>`` You put the backtick as *part* of the string, not as the delimiters. Change to ``text: `<p>...`` (same for the ending delimiter)

Comment: Though, this will make it impossible for obsolete browsers that don't support ES6 to parse your code, so it would probably be better to remove the newlines programmatically than to use a template literal.

Comment: This is not a `liquid` nor a `jekyll` problem. I've removed the tags. If you have a problem with the generated code it's a javascript problem. So, you must paste the generated code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It works now. Thanks. I will try to remove newline programmatically.

Comment: @David Jacquel Thanks for editing.

Comment: @DavidJacquel IMO the issue *is* sufficiently related - the problem relates to how the (non-Javascript) template is being translated into the code. (but, the question boils down to what's essentially a typo, so it's off-topic anyway...)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm ok with you comment. I was trying to help to narrow down the problem [after this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53977921/1548376).